# How to get multiple rows data of the form in controller in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have to show/edit a form in my page. I'm fetching all rows from table and showing in table format which is editable.
Once the table is edited. I want all those rows to update in database using controller, however I dont know how to get all form rows through request object in laravel 5.1.

```
$records = $request->all();
```

As request object giving only last row of the form.
Any suggestion?

```html
@section('content')
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'madcat/update', 'method' => 'put', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) !!}
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
    <div class="form-group">                
        <table class=" table table-condensed">
        <thead> 
         <tr> 
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Field</th> 
          <th>Max</th>
             <th>Min</th>
         </tr> 
        </thead>
        @foreach($records as $key => $value)
          <tr>
           <td>{!!Form::text('id',$value->id,['readonly'])!!}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::checkbox('Field_check'.$value->id)!!}{!! Form::text('Field',$value->Field,['readonly'])!!}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::checkbox('Max_check'.$value->id)!!}{!! Form::text('Max',$value->Max,['readonly'],array('size'=>'4'))!!}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::checkbox('Min_check'.$value->id)!!}{!!Form::text('Min', $value->Min,['readonly'],array('size'=>'4'))!!}</td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-11">
        {!!Form::submit('Save', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'))!!}
        
  </div>
    </div>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
@endsection
```

This is the code of HTML. Here I will check the checkbox in front of all the rows element so that I want to update only those rows in another table.

Comment: the code of the html form could help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that all checkboxes have the same name in the loop. 
You need something like this

```
{!!Form::checkbox('Field_check' . $key )!!}
{!!Form::checkbox('Max_check' . $key)!!}
{!!Form::checkbox('Min_check' . $key)!!}
```

Otherwise PHP can't tell you which row you edit.

Comment: Checkbox names changed. How to get all the rows through request object in controller?

Comment: Loop through `Request::all();` extract the number at the end.

Comment: all form values are coming in single array. Can we get it row by row?

Comment: Name the checkboxes e.g. 
`{!!Form::checkbox('check' . $value->id . '[field]' )!!}` 
`{!!Form::checkbox('check' . $value->id . '[max]' )!!}` 
`{!!Form::checkbox('check' . $value->id . '[min]' )!!}` 
then you get an array for each row. If you want all form elements in a array you have to change their names to.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the answer . Actually mistake was the naming of all the form elements

```html
@section('content')
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'madcat/update', 'method' => 'put', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')) !!}
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
    <div class="form-group">                
        <table class=" table table-condensed">
        <thead> 
         <tr> 
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Field</th> 
          <th>Max</th>
             <th>Min</th>
         </tr> 
        </thead>
        @foreach($records as $key => $value)
          <tr>
           <td>{!!Form::text('id'.$value->id,$value->id,['readonly'])!!}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::checkbox('Field_check'.$value->id)!!}{!! Form::text('Field'.$value->id,$value->Field,['readonly'])!!}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::checkbox('Max_check'.$value->id)!!}{!! Form::text('Max'.$value->id,$value->Max,['readonly'],array('size'=>'4'))!!}</td>
            <td>{!!Form::checkbox('Min_check'.$value->id)!!}{!!Form::text('Min'.$value->id, $value->Min,['readonly'],array('size'=>'4'))!!}</td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-11">
        {!!Form::submit('Save', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'))!!}
        
  </div>
    </div>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
@endsection
```

Made changes in the names of all the form elements and I got all values in the request object.

Comment: ... this is my answer... not yours. You just take other ids than me